# Firebase trying to connect with a test phone number raise an error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using a firebase sms verification in my application. I have added months ago a test phone number on my firebase phone method. That phone number works just fine, I can authenticate to my app normally.

I have decided to add a new developer phone number, a real phone number of mine. But then when I try to authenticate I'm facing the above error:

> FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ DEVELOPMENT_MODE_MISMATCH:Non-development mode Verification Proof given in development mode request.

I don't know why the old test number works just fine while my new one not.

Is adding a new test phone number takes time to updated? A real phone number is not able to be a tested?

Thanks

Comment: Is an application published on google play ?

Comment: No right now I'm just creating an apk and then `flutter install` to my physical device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, I had to **wait for two hours** to my new test phone number to take place on firebase. Now the auth is working just fine.